# How can I disable custom setup type and display only the installation path in WiX

Tags: wix

My Installer required all the wizard options so I used WixUI_Mondo. That displays all the setup optoins: ( `Typical, Custom and Complete` ).

As per my requirement the `Custom` type shouldn't be displayed. By default the package so install under program files.

How can I disable this feature also just would like to display like "C:\Program Files\MyProduct" in the setup type screen?

```
<Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Program' Description='The main executable.' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />      
</Feature>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don’t want to use Custom Setup, then go for WixUI_InstallDir. It has Install Directories option.

If you want to modify anything in Custom Setup, use Wix Source code.  Inside the Source code you can find the UI WXS files in below location.

```
src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib
```

Open **WixUI_Mondo.WXS** file and Copy all coding inside the Fragment and use it in your project. If you modify the Dialog publish sequence you can do anything, (Adding Custom dialog or disabling existing dialog, etc.)

**Note:** You can download the Source Code from [here](http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16a8b5dbf828f92e28138ce3c9ee852affeaa1ef).

Comment: It looks a bit more complex. Could you please suggest any one of the easiest option? This is the end step to complete my installer

Comment: @Vinoth gave you two correct options. The first option is definitely easiest.

Comment: hi rob. As per your guideline i changed WixUI_InstallDir instead of WixUI_Mondo. But It is giving error "The installer encounter an unexpected error. The error code is 2819" after license screen it's giving issue. pls help me

Comment: Use WIXUI_INSTALLDIR property. Please check WixUI Dialog Library in WiX Documentation for more details.